# How to edit a column in Libre Office Calc to set all URLs as clickable links?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a column with many URLs, some of them are not clickable (as blue), I need to select one by one, then ctrl+x, ctrl+v, then enter to transform URLs as text to HTTP links.

It's very annoying, I have tons of URLs, I'm pretty sure something exists to render all as clickable links.

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe [this dirty hack](https://superuser.com/a/394170/84724) works in your case, too? It does nearly the same: replace a cell's content with its current content.

Comment: Thanks, tested both `&` and `&\n`, none works. I need to type enter at each row

Comment: Tested also a blank newline without success

Answer (score -1):

Here's a Basic macro for LibreOffice Calc to make clickable links of
URL strings in a selected 1-column sheet cell range. It skips any
blank, numeric, or datetime cells but assumes text cells each contain
a valid URL.
To avoid accidental activation aborts with a message box if more than
one column selected or a blank cell in first row. No harm done if run
twice. Ctrl-Z to undo effects 1 cell at a time.

If copied to a module under `My Macros` (Tools | Macros | Organise …)
it should be available to all Calc sheets.

Credits go to Andrew Pitonyak from whose [OOo Macro](https://pitonyak.org/oo.php)
document the essentials were snipped.

```
Sub ActivateUrlsAsLinks
    Const boxtitle = "URL activator"
    Dim msg As String
    Dim oSels As Object, cell As Object
    oSels = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getSelection()
    cell = oSels.getCellByPosition(0, 0)

    If oSels.Columns.getCount <> 1 Or cell.getString() = "" Then
        msg = "Select cell range with URLs to be converted to clickable links, " & _
              "then run this macro." & _
              Chr(10) &  Chr(10) & "NB: 1 column, and a URL in first row."
        MsgBox msg, MB_ICONSTOP, boxtitle
    Else
        Dim txtfld As Object, celltxt As Object
        Dim rix As Integer, subs As Integer, cstr as String
        subs = 0
        For rix = 0 To oSels.Rows.getCount - 1
            cell = oSels.getCellByPosition(0, rix)
            cstr = cell.getString()
            If Len(Trim(cstr)) > 0 And Not IsNumeric(cstr) And Not IsDate(cstr) Then
                txtfld = ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextField.URL")
                txtfld.Representation = cstr
                txtfld.URL = ConvertToURL(cstr)
                cell.setString("")
                celltxt = cell.getText()
                celltxt.insertTextContent(celltxt.createTextCursor(), txtfld, False)
                subs = subs + 1
            End If
        Next rix
        msg = "Replaced " & subs & " cells"
        MsgBox msg, MB_ICONINFORMATION, boxtitle
    End If
End Sub
```