# How to force LibreOffice Calc to treat time values as numbers

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to do something very simple in LibreOffice Calc:

I have a set of simple CSV files that contain lists of durations, formatted as HH:MM:SS.

I need to make a SUM of those lists.

With some research, I figured out that the thing to do is to change the formatting of the cells, as it is explained here: [LibreOffice Calc: How to get total for HH:MM:SS cells](https://superuser.com/questions/387106/libreoffice-calc-how-to-get-total-for-hhmmss-cells)

The problem is: LibreOffice doesn't really apply this formatting to my cells.

If I type manually a value inside such a formatted cell, an entry such as 00:01.58 is treated correctly as a "time" value, gets aligned right, and adds to the final SUM.

However, all the values already present in the CSV aren't converted. They remain aligned left, and are considered as dumb strings. They remain firmly aligned left, and add nothing to the final SUM.

If I place my cursor at the end of one of those cells, and hit the "enter" key, LibreOffice transforms it into a number and aligns it right, and adds the duration to the end SUM. But I don't want to do this manually for hundreds of cells...

This is driving me nuts. How can I convince LibreOffice that those fields have to be treated as numeric time values?

Using LibreOffice 4.1.4.2 on OSX 10.9.1.

Comment: Try the solution proposed [here](http://superuser.com/a/394170/84724). I'm almost sure that LO handles the time values in a correct way after the search/replace described there.

Comment: Thanks @tohuwawohu for this helpful link, it was exactly that. Those solutions work indeed.