# LibreOffice Calc won't sum time over 24 hours

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

Libre Office Version: 5.2.5.1

Adding a column of hours:minutes (example: 5:30 + 3:00 + 12:30) that totals more than 23:59 gives 00:00.

Apparently hours over 24 = 1 day, so the clock starts over, but I don't see how to add a column that might have more (40?) hours in it. Other time formats do not seem to help, except I did get a correct answer breifly with one of the HH:MM:SS formats. However, it reverted to 00:00:0 after a few runs.

What to do?

Sample data:

[image]

Formula:

```
=((ENTRY.F7<ENTRY.G7)+ENTRY.G7-ENTRY.F7)+ENTRY.E7+ENTRY.H7
```

Comment: In excel, so I do not know if it works for LibreOffice, on would use the format: `[HH]:MM:SS` with the `HH` in `[]`.  Not sure if that works in LibreOffice hence the comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks, tried 24:30, discovered that the original colum, which is filled with data from another page, does NOT give the correct time total, but a test colume with the same numbers, typed into the cells, is correct, including product > 24 hrs - bafflled

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Please [edit] the question **not** my answer. Your formula does not match your sample data image. That makes it useless - I am trying to reproduce your problem. If you can't [edit] the question and provide suitable sample data I will give up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibreOffice Calc: How to get total for HH:MM:SS cells](http://superuser.com/questions/387106/libreoffice-calc-how-to-get-total-for-hhmmss-cells)

Comment: @tohuwawohu We already know the duplicate doesn't fix his problem. See the comments under my answer.

Answer (score 4):

#### I don't see how to add a column that might have more (40?) hours in it

As pointed out in a comment by [Scott Craner](https://superuser.com/users/567231/scott-craner), format the total cell as `[HH]:MM:SS`:

[image]

Tested with LibreOffice Calc 5.2.4.2.

Comment: This gives 140:30:00.00

Comment: column is formatted HH:MM, sum() cell is [HH]:MM:SS.00

Comment: input cells:  =IF(ENTRY.G13="","",((ENTRY.F13<ENTRY.G13)+ENTRY.G13-ENTRY.F13)+ENTRY.E13+ENTRY.H13)

Comment: @baffled <shrug> It works for me ...

Comment: Must be your `IF` command breaking it ...

Comment: removed IF() still giives 144:30, should be 24:30 ... =((ENTRY.F7<ENTRY.G7)+ENTRY.G7-ENTRY.F7)+ENTRY.E7+ENTRY.H7

Comment: Please edit the question to include some sample data. See my comment on the question.

Comment: too  much comment, not enough "reputation" to chat. [HH] worked in test colume where input is typed in. Will experiment. Probably have to go to entering hours as general numbers, ie, "25.75" hours for "25:45". Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: You don't need rep to edit the question. Use the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: could not make this interface work, not a smart rat. added columns from notepad, did not format in edit, I give up, sorry.

Comment: You are supposed to edit the question not my answer. My comment under your question gives a way to format the data as a table. Please use it.

Comment: Or you can post screenshots, showing the source data for your formula ...

Comment: I believe I will have to test for >24 hrs and calculate the correct display